# Cannot run most cordova commands without using sudo

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, osx-yosemite

I have installed npm to setup Ionic & Cordova - and I have used sudo for this?

My question is when I run the following command without sudo I get an error:

```
cordova emulate ios
```

The error is an

```
EACCES, permission denied ..... /ios.json
```

Am I right that if I cannot use this 'basic' cordova command without running sudo my installation has been screwed up somehow?

Comment: You should not use sudo to install global npm packages. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did the following on the terminal to allow me to run the commands without using sudo (this might help someone)

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Documents/mobileapps
```

This meant the cordova emulate ios command now runs! finally!

Comment: Yes, it helped me! I had an additional issue however -- cordova commands such as $ cordova plugins or even cordova help were failing with the same error message. Fixed with the same trick: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/USERNAME/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json  I suspect however that this means something more profound went wrong with my last update.