# i have to use sudo -E run android instead of ionic run android in ubuntu why any one can give the answer

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework, ionic2, ubuntu-16.04

when i use command in **ubuntu 16.04**

```
sudo ionic run android
```

it gives error like

> ANDROID_HOME environment veriables is not set

but when i use command

```
sudo -E ionic run android
```

its perfectly run without error, any one can answer this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `sudo` it allows you to run commands with root privileges and it also uses root environment. Your ANDROID_HOME variable is set for the local user and not root.This throws error.

`sudo -E` instructs sudo to  use the current user environment which will pick up ANDROID_HOME.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219565/cannot-run-most-cordova-commands-without-using-sudo) to fix permission issue for running `ionic/cordova` commands.